# Key terms, multiple-output battery voltage regulator

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator

I'm working on a space limited project, using an LI2430 rechargeable Li-Ion coin cell battery.

I need to power a `2V7` LED rail, and a `3V3` VCC rail.

I want to find an IC that can take in my VBatt input (`3v7` down to as low as `2V4`), and steadily (`+-0V25`) output these two voltage levels.

Are such ICs common? And if so, what keywords might I use to find them? If not, what would the best solution be? My best guess would be a buck-boost converter and LDO regulators.

Thoughts?

Comment: What are your current requirements for each rail?  What's stopping you from powering the LEDs off of 3V3?  In short, no, dual-independent buck-boost converters (which is what you'll need) are not common.  A quick look on Digikey showed no such devices though I might have missed them.  If your LED rail doesn't take too much current, a LDO powered from your 3V3 rail would almost certainly take up less real estate than a separate buck-boost.

Comment: LEDs should be run from a current-limited supply, not from a fixed voltage supply.  If you have multiple LEDs, each LED should have its own current limiter (usually a resistor).

Comment: I’m using a TI constant current LED common-cathode driver (TLC5941RHBR), so no need for resistors, I just need to set the voltage that matches my current setting.